# How to set Cookie in Laravel in view file

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-5

I want to create a cookie in the View File(example.blade.php). I want to create cookie in the masterfile.blade.php which is in layouts directory so I dont have a controller. In another controller and another view I am able to set cookie but I want cookie to be set when the application starts. How can I do this. I have done it in controller but I dont know how can i use directly in view, someone help.

```
$cookie_value= rand(1000,10000).$timestamp;
        $view = View::make('shop.show',compact('productTabs','product','storename','business'));
        $cookie = Cookie::make('gdoox_shopping_cart', $cookie_value, 1000);
        return Response::make($view)->withCookie($cookie);
```

Comment: You say you want to do this from a view, but you also say you want to do it "when the application starts". Which is it?

Comment: @MarkAmery: I meant to say I want set cookie in my home page. I want to do this in View.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Global Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#registering-middleware) to set your cookie if its not set already.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!$request->hasCookie('gdoox_shopping_cart')) {
        $cookie_value= rand(1000,10000).$timestamp;

        return $next($request)->headers->setCookie(Cookie::make('gdoox_shopping_cart', $cookie_value, 1000));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Don't forget to register your Middleware in the middleware attribute in Http/Kernel.php

Comment: I think doing this in Route will set a new cookie everytime the view is rendered. I want to set only one time if the cookie is not set in the users browser.

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to do here

Comment: I am working in a shopping cart. I just want to set a cookie on the users browser if he comes to the website. Now if he adds any products to the cart without login, i can track those products with this cookie id. So first thing I want to do is set a cookie, I can do it the PHP way (setcookie() function) in the view file directly but I was finding a solution using Laravel. The solution you gave me  above is not working for me, it does not set cookie. For now I have done it the PHP way but i think its not a good idea when using frameworks.

Comment: Ok I've edited my answer, let me know if you have issues